# How do i make my react web appp to appear on google search?

Tags: reactjs, search, deployment, seo

I made a web app with React, everything working fine. I deployed with heroku and used a custom domain. But the thing is how do i make to appear it on google search? Like if you put facebook, you have the link for the webpage in the search results.
I do not want to lose the dynamic changes of the hmtl that react offers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it takes time for google to search a site. A XML site-map always helps googles crawlers and makes it more accesible for them. If your site has some time already you can ask for it to be indexed by contacting google.

Comment: Thanks, I went to google search console and upload my sitemap.xml. Also I did some good SEO practices with my react app, and now it appears on Google. It took about 24 hours in showing changes.

Comment: i have same problem , its 6 days im waiting for google to crawl but without sitemap ,
today i also put sitemap
, is this Enough?
i mean there is no need to use ssr and google can crawl my site just with a simple sitemap ?

Comment: The sitemap helps and it depends on what you used to build the site. You can contact google and ask for your site to be indexed in https://search.google.com/search-console/about